# can i change user model credentials in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am building an API for login and registration using loopback framework.
Loopback provides, by default, model `User` for login, register and other similar stuff. Default way to provide user's credentials in LoopBack is username-password/email-password but I want to use mobileNo-password/email-password as user's login credentials. So how can I do that? How can I change default `credential` option in `User` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways:

1. If not using `username` field in `User` model, you can use it to store mobile number, `mobileNo`.
2. You have to edit `user.js` to accept `mobileNo` field as login credentials. `User.login` and `User.normalizeCredentials` are used for login process, so you can edit them like provided in the code snippet.

**Note**: Don't forget to add `mobileNo` to `user.json`

**User.normalizeCredentials method**

```
`User.normalizeCredentials = function(credentials, realmRequired, realmDelimiter) {
    var query = {};
    credentials = credentials || {};
    if (!realmRequired) {
        if (credentials.email) {
            query.email = credentials.email;
        } else if (credentials.mobileNo) {
            query.mobileNo = credentials.mobileNo;
        }
    } else {
        if (credentials.realm) {
            query.realm = credentials.realm;
        }
        var parts;
        if (credentials.email) {
            parts = splitPrincipal(credentials.email, realmDelimiter);
            query.email = parts[1];
            if (parts[0]) {
                query.realm = parts[0];
            }
        } else if (credentials.mobileNo) {    //added mobileNo.
            parts = splitPrincipal(credentials.mobileNo, realmDelimiter);
            query.mobileNo = parts[1];
            if (parts[0]) {
                query.realm = parts[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return query;
};`
```

**User.login method**

```
`User.login = function(credentials, include, fn) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    if (!query.email && !query.mobileNo) {
        var err2 = new Error('Mobile number or email is required');
        err2.statusCode = 400;
        err2.code = 'MOBILE_NUMBER_EMAIL_REQUIRED';
        fn(err2);
        return fn.promise;
    }
}`
```

Comment: one more question, How can i skip email in registration(user.Create)?

Comment: remove `required: true` from `user.json` for `email` field.